# Square of a normally distributed variable

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose $X$ is normal with mean $\theta$, and variance equal to 1. What is the distribution of $X^2$?

Comment: Why are short concise questions so often considered to be low quality?  If it is a duplicate close it for that reason.

Comment: @Michael, if it's a duplicate (which this certainly is, many times over), *please close it as one*. Search for a duplicate (which may be more convenient done in another tab), click close on this, click through to closing as duplicate, paste in the url. If you make a reasonable attempt to find one and can't, then sure, answer it (unless it looks like homework...) -- but a duplicate of this one could be found by basic searching (like *square of a normal*)

Comment: I am not surprised.  I was just responding to it being in the queue as low quality.  I am not surprised that you found other questions that are duplicates. I just left it for someone else to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\theta=0$, $X^2$ is a central chi-square with 1 degree of freedom.  If $\theta\neq 0$, $X^2$ is a non-central chi-square with 1 degree of freedom and $\theta$ the non-centrality parameter.

Comment: Sometimes as described in wikipedia $\theta$$^2$ is referred to as the non-centrality parameter. This generalizes when you sum the squares of several i.i.d. normal random variables with variance 1.